# How to validate a stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to validate the parameters in the stored procedure in SQL Server i.e. whether the parameter value is correct or not, and return that invalid parameter back with query,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_test
    (@Para1 int, 
     @para2 bigint,
     @para3 varchar)
```

If I pass string value to the int parameter or vice-versa, how to validate in the SQL Server side?

Or if there is a function for this to call for various parameters and datatype to check from the SQL Server side.

Comment: You can't pass a string for an `int` parameter and there's no need to even try to validate types - SQL Server will perform an implicit conversion which will either succeed (e.g. `'1' --> 1` or fail `'a' --> error`). What you should be validating is `NULL` vs `NOT NULL` as procedure parameters (unfortunately) cannot have null constraints, unlike table-columns.

Comment: @Dai ,  when the datatype is smallint or tinyint, from the frondend side some time they will pass intiger value, or in the case of datetime, they will pass disorder datetype format as string., in such case how to validate, if this type error comes, it will showing the other  parameter value instead of the exact parameter value which got error. mabe be the fifth parameter got error , but it may show 20th parameter having error.

Comment: You validate it according to whatever rules you want to, but as already said, you can't pass an incorrect datatype in anyway, your calling application needs to validate. And return the validation results any way you like,  but `THROW` is probably best.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `If param1 > {max-small-int-size} throw 'param1 invalid'`?

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the advice . i will follow this methods form now onwards

Comment: Aside... by itself `varchar` is not a data type. You need to be specific and always define a length, e.g.: `varchar(10)`.

Answer (score -1):

With the Below function I have tried and I got the method in success , if it returns zero the process will error with the passed parameter.

```
Create Function Dbo.ValidationProcess
(
@Value Varchar(250),
@DataType varchar(50)
)
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @VAR TINYINT=1
         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='INT')
         BEGIN
                  SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                  RETURN @VAR
         END
         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='SMALLINT')
         BEGIN
                 SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(SMALLINT, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                  RETURN @VAR
         END
         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='TINYINT')
         BEGIN
                 SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TINYINT, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                  RETURN @VAR
         END
         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='DECIMAL')
         BEGIN
                SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                 RETURN @VAR
         END

         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='BIGINT')
         BEGIN
                SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                 RETURN @VAR
         END

         IF(UPPER(@DATATYPE)='DATETIME')
         BEGIN
                SET @VAR=(SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE) IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END)
                RETURN @VAR
         END
          RETURN @VAR

END
```

Comment: The `UPPER()` calls are unnecessary as string comparison is case-insensitive by default - and if the DB is configured to use case-sensitive collation by default you can always use a specific collation for the comparison. Secondly, this function should be marked as inlineable (`WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON` ) otherwise it will prevent queries being parallizable. Third, using `SET @var = ( SELECT CASE`) is also unnecessary: you can do it as `SET @var = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT IS`. Finally, `RETURNS tinyint` should be `RETURNS bit`, otherwise it's unclear what a return value between 2-255 means.